# Checking SMS sending status iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

It's possible to check SMS sending status? e.g.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController * smsPicker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

smsPicker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

smsPicker.body = @"Body";

[self presentModalViewController:smsPicker animated:YES];

[smsPicker release];
```

I don't know why, but the delegate 
    - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller      didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result; executing before sending and works if user cancelled SMS.

And I need to know, if SMS sent or failed (e.g. cell network error or something wrong). Thanks for future help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `result` parameter `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` to check the status of the message. Its type is [MessageComposeResult](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MessageComposeResult):

```
enum MessageComposeResult {
   MessageComposeResultCancelled,
   MessageComposeResultSent,
   MessageComposeResultFailed
};
```

Bear in mind that `MessageComposeResultSent` may only be interpreted as a **successful queueing of the message for later sending. The actual send will occur when the device is able to send.**

---

> How can I check if device is able to send?

To test whether a device is capable of sending text messages, use `MFMessageComposeViewController`'s [canSendText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText) class method. According to the documentation, *you should always call this method before attempting to present the message compose view controller.*

However, this will not tell you if the device is able to send the message *now* (in case you asked with this statement in mind: *The actual send will occur when the device is able to send*).

Comment: As I said it works only for Cancelled. It returns status Sent before SMS sent. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: That's because `MessageComposeResultSent` means that the message has successfully been *queued* or sent.

Comment: How can I check if device is able to send?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does not account for cell network interruptions at the very least. For example when in airplane mode the delegate receives a `MessageComposeResultSent`!

I have filed a radar for [this](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1074401). Duplicating it may get the issue resolved sooner.

Comment: Thank you! Please notify me if you will find solution.

Comment: Presently I use the MessageComposeResult at face value and don't do any checks for network availability.